# I'm trying to read a CSV file and display it in excel as a csv file

Tags: java

***I'm having error that states:

> Error: Main method not found in class Main, please define the main method as:
>   public static void main(String[] args)
>   I solved the previous issue but I'm now getting this error: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe (Nov 8, 2015, 7:41:12 PM)
>   When attempting to run this code:***
>       package filtermovingaverage;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    //public static void main(String[] args){


    private static double freqS = 100;
    static ArrayList<Double> sec = null; 
    private static double[] pressure = new double[20481];

    void func() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\KwakuK\\Downloads\\smith2.csv")));        
        String currentLine = new String();
        currentLine = read.readLine();
        int i = 0;
        //make some computation
        while((currentLine = read.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] numbers = currentLine.split(","); // split the string into sub strings
            if(numbers.length >= 3)
            {
                    System.out.println("currentLine: " + " " + currentLine);

                pressure[i++] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[2]); // when you do the 2, it's the third column which is the pressure
            }
        }
    }

    public static void setupFirstPlot() throws FileNotFoundException{
        sec = new ArrayList<Double>();
        double ws = 1/freqS;
        double n = (pressure.length)*ws;

        for(double i = 0; i < n; i = i + ws){ 
            sec.add(i);
        }
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("plot13.csv"));
        for(int i = 0; i < pressure.length; i++){
            pw.write(sec.get(i)+","+pressure[i]+"\n");
        }
        pw.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        setupFirstPlot();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you probably want to check out Apache POI; it's a library that helps you create Excel spreadsheets (among others).

Comment: As mentioned [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html) is a great library. However, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code. It obviously has a main method.  What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using JavaSE-1.7

Comment: I just cut and pasted your code in to eclipse(JSE 1.8), It seemed to run just fine.  It created the plot13 file.  The func() is never called and would do little good without the .../smith2.csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `package filtermovingaverage;` to the top of this java file.